# Moment.js calander method gives incorrect time when converting timestamp

Tags: momentjs

I am obtaining records from SQL Server database which contain time stamp column which looks like this:

```
"2020-08-15T22:57:19.000Z"
```

I am using the moment.js library to obtain a user friendly date value. But when I do:

moment( "2020-08-15T22:57:19.000Z").calendar()

I am getting

```
Today at 6:57 PM
```

instead of

```
Today at 10:57 PM
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with time zone shift. I suspect your browser is running in a location that's 4 hours away from UTC. Have you tried any of the different parse options here? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/troubleshooting/  "Ambiguous input is assumed to be UTC. Unambiguous input is adjusted to UTC."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.utc()` function and [.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function of `momentJs` to get your desired results. You do **not** need to use `calender()`

**Live Demo:**

```js
let dbData = '2020-08-15T22:57:19.000Z'
let getTime = moment(dbData).utc().format('hh:mm A') 
console.log('Today at ' + getTime) //10:57 PM
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right I was able to to do `moment(2020-08-15T22:57:19.000Z).utc().calendar()`  to get what I wanted